# How to rename a directory whose name starts with an upper-case letter to the same name with a lower-case letter?

Tags: bash

UPDATE : As @ctrl-alt-delor mentioned this was because the file system (fuseblk) I was on is "case preserving" but "case ignoring".

=====

I know this not a big usecase, but at least to understand the root of the issue and because I do that a lot:

`mv` and `mkdir` or something else in the shell involved in the process of `mkdir` is case sensitive and leads me to the errors :

```
x@host :/ $ ls
Dir 

x@host :/ $ mv Dir/ dir
mv: cannot move 'Dir/' to a subdirectory of itself, 'dir/Dir'

x@host :/ $ mkdir dir
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘dir’: File exists
```

Is there a simple trick that would allow this to be done in one command ?

PS : The quickest way I found is by

```
mkdir tmp ; cd tmp ; mkdir dir ; mv ../Dir/* dir/ ; cd .. ; rm -r Dir ; mv tmp/dir . ; rm -r tmp
```

CONFIG : Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: What file system?

Comment: It's on an external hdd and df -T gives "fuseblk" for this... is it right ?

Comment: Instead of `mv Dir/ dir` can you try `mv Dir dir`

Comment: yes already tried it's the same

Comment: @MarkPlotnick the problem is that it is on a not-unix file-system (case preserving but case ignoring).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should not be using a fat file-system for your home directory; Use ext4.

Here is the easiest, and quickest way that I know of (it has a time and memory complexity of O(1): no copying )

```
mv -T Dir dir-tmp-name; mv -T dir-tmp-name dir
```

If your `mv` does not support `-T`, then you can unsafely leave it out. Gnu `mv` does support it.

Comment: It's not my home... I just replaced the real info by something general. My home is in ext4

Comment: haha yes, your solution is very much quicker, I don't know why I missed that ! Thanks for the help !

Comment: Did you mean, `mv -T Dir dir-tmp-name; mv -T dir-tmp-name dir`? Your temporary directory names are not the same.

Comment: @scribe yes fixed.